# Spring @Bean will it be autowired if the class auto scanned

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I read about the component scan and as I understood that configuration classes are auto-scanned. my question if I have the following:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
@Bean(name="authenticationService")
    public AuthenticationService getAuthenticationService(){
        return new AuthenticationService();
    }
}
```

if the @Configuration is already scanned (so the app config will be available ), wouldn't be the bean inside it created? I'm little confused as they say the @Bean is not auto scanned

Comment: No, it won't. If you want spring to create the bean of AuthenticationService in AppConfig, just use @Autowired.
`@Autowired
private AuthenticationService authenticationService;`

Comment: The answer to your question is no it won't scan `@Bean` methods as there is nothing to scan. But the answer you want is yes an instance of `AuthenticationService` will be created because that is the whole point of having a `@Bean` method. So no `@Bean` aren't scanned they are merely indicates of bean creation methods. Just like the `<bean />` element in XML.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so the bean will be created once the class auto scanned right?

Answer (score -1):

No. Spring won't scan `@Bean` methods.

Here, you are creating the bean of `AuthenticationService` just like in any other java program using `new` keyword.

It is same as `AuthenticationService authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();`

If you want spring to create a bean of `AuthenticationService` in `AppConfig` class, use `@Autowired` annotation

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT :**

@M.Deinum corrected me that spring doesn't create beans based on `@Autowired` annotation. Beans are created automatically by spring if their classes are annotated with @Component/ @Configuration / @Service annotations.

@M.Deinum, Thank you.

Comment: My main question will that bean be seen by auto scan ? As the @Bean is not discovered by component scan. If its not detected how spting figure it

Comment: No it won't. `@Autowired` creates nothing, it is only a marker/trigger that you want something of that type injected. That type has to be either component scanned and itself annotated with `@Component` or created in a `@Configuration` class using a `@Bean` method (or the equivalent in XML `<bean />`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, have added `So to sum up, spring will only create the beans marked with @Autowired annotation.` in the end. Is that a wrong statement? I know annotations do nothing except the metadata part. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: No that is completely wrong. `@Autowired` has nothing to do with bean creation.

Comment: okies. gotcha..!! Many Thanks. Beans are created if we mark with `@Component/ @Configuration/ @Service` annotations but not with `@Autowired`. Something important I learnt today.. :)